# Adding data to multiple records

Tags: gis, postgis

I have a project with various parts.... One of which is the calculate the area of all the polygons on a map.   When I run the query "select st_area(nycpp.the_geom) from nycpp;"  I get a list of all the areas.

Next, I tried adding the results of the query to the nycpp table with 
UPDATE nycpp SET area_sizes = (select st_area(nycpp.the_geom) from nycpp);
but get the error -- "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

I figured out why am I getting the error... what I can not figure out is how write a script that will update all 12K+ records....

Can someone give an example or a link to info on updating multiple records

The database I'm using is PostGIS

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it to complicated. Try:

UPDATE nycpp set area_sizes=ST_Area(the_geom);